# How to upload file in binary format using ng-file upload library in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

I am uploading a file to Amazon S3 Bucket using pre-signed URL from AngularJs. Zip file getting corrupted while opening the downloaded file. It is working as expected when I upload the file from postman in binary format.

[image]

I am using ng-file-upload library in angularjs. For every downloaded file contains web-kit form boundary appended in the beginning as follows:

[image]

If we edit and remove the web-kit form boundary and try to open the same file its opening perfectly.

Comment: Could you provide a code being used to download a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem the week ago and the only solution I came up with, was to write my own code which sends files via http request. Feel free to use the example:

```js
function azureChangeFn() {
   var inputElement = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
   var newFile = inputElement.files[0];
   var url = "https://YOUR_STORAGE_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER_NAME/"+ newFile.name +"GENERATED_SharedAccessSignature_FROM_AZURE_SITE";
   
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
     alert("Sent to azure storage service!");
    }
   }
   xhr.open('PUT', url, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("lng", "en");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ms-blob-content-type", newFile.type);
   xhr.send(newFile);
  }
  
  function updateProgress (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
   var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
   console.log(percentComplete);
    } else {
   alert('FAIL');
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Example without library:</label>
  <br>
  <label>Select file: <input type="file" id="fileSelect" onchange="azureChangeFn()"></label>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Talking about ng-file-upload library, in source code I found that **formData.append** method when appending a file, automaticaly adds web-kit header. As far as I understood, FormData is used for POST method, but when using PUT all body is taken as a file. Sadly I was unable to upload file to azure storage with POST method.